# Is it possible to set Sessions on all templates when created?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In Meteor, there is currently a `Template.registerHelper` method.  Is it possible to set something like a `Template.registeronCreated` so that a certain Session variable is set on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
 Session.setDefault("globalSession",value)
```

So this session will be avaible on all the application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a created function to your template instance that will be called when the template is created:

```
Template.myTemplate.created = function() {
  Session.set('foo', 'bar);
};
```